# Selenium WebDriver commen

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Here is the python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import subprocess

EXTENSION_PATH = "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/10.17.0_0.crx" 

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
time.sleep(1)
```

I try to run the program I get the following error:**(file name: 1.py)**

```
"C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" c:/Users/HP/Desktop/py/1.py
c:\Users\HP\Desktop\py\1.py:27: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\py\1.py", line 27, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

I put all the required files in the patch.
I am using a windows

Comment: Try setting the location to the chromedriver.exe explicitly `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
```

with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe", options=opt)
```

You should be good to go.

Your effective code block will be:

```
EXTENSION_PATH = "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/10.17.0_0.crx" 

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe", options=opt)
```

Comment: `opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
time.sleep(1)`

Comment: The same warning came again

Comment: The same warning came again –